# Temporal clustering in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, cluster-analysis, aggregation-framework

Given a user schema that includes an event log, how would you identify temporal event clusters; e.g., *n* or more events within *m* seconds? Each user might look like this, and I'm interested in all users:

```
{
 _id: ...
 name: ...
 events: [{foo: bar, date: Date}, ...]
}
```

Comment: With MongoDB? srsly? Get the data out, analyze outside, put the results back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only the tools in MongoDB, your best option would be to split the events into time buckets, and use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) to do analysis on these buckets.

The first step is to restructure your schema.  It is better to put each event in its own document to allow more flexible querying and to prevent the need for documents to grow when adding new events.  See the documentation on [Normalized Data Models](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-model-design/#normalized-data-models).

For example, you may have two collections: `users` and `events`, where `events.user` refers to the owning `user`.

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId,
    name: string
}

{
    _id: ObjectId,
    user: ObjectId,
    date: Date,
    date_ms: Integer
}
```

You can then use the following query to find one-minute intervals containing more than 100 events:

```js
db.events.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: {$subtract: ["$date_ms", { $mod: ["$date_ms", 60*1000]} ]},
        count: { $sum: 1 }}},
    {$match: {"count": {$gt: 100}}}
])
```

Be aware that this query is not a perfect solution: it will not return a cluster of events that is split across a bucket boundary.  For more sophisticated logic, you will have to do analysis in your application.